# Google Analytics Content Experiments - Disregard my visits

Tags: google-analytics, google-experiments

I'm running a Google Analytics A/B testing (aka Experiment), but the client is asking me to make some minor changes and annoyingly - even though I'm logged in with my GA account - I appear to be skewing the results with my visits to the page. Could this be happening?

There presumably must be some way to ensure that GA ignores me? No amount of searching is bringing me closer to an answer :(

Comment: Ruling out the obvious: have you included a filter to filter out your visits?

Comment: Official Google Analytics opt-out plugin: https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout. Some practical advice: http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/with-your-own-ga-requests-dont-exclude-rewrite/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add your IP in the filter, in this case, analytics will ignore you

and you always can check realtime reports

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. You might also want to clarify how this can be done, and provide links to other resources.